# How to loop items in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, multilingual, mongoose-schema

I have mongoose Schema , where i have schemas by language. I want to loop them depend my other language model. Now I have them static(en, ru, ge).

```
const StrategyTranslatedFieldsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: String,
    teaser: String
  },
  { _id : false }
)

const StrategySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    en: StrategyTranslatedFieldsSchema,
    ge: StrategyTranslatedFieldsSchema,
    ru: StrategyTranslatedFieldsSchema,
},
{
    timestamps: true 
});
```

my language schema:

```
const languageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    en:{
        type: String,
        default: 'en'
    },
    ru:{
        type: String,
        default: 'ru'
    },
    ge:{
        type: String,
        default: 'ge'
    },
})
```

want something like that:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slug = require('mongoose-slug-updater');
const Language = require('../models/Language')

mongoose.plugin(slug); 

const StrategyTranslatedFieldsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: String,
    teaser: String
  },
  { _id : false }
)

const StrategySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  slug: { 
    type: String, 
    slug: "en.title", 
    slugPaddingSize: 2,  
    unique: true 
  },
  status:{
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
    for(let key in Language){
    key: StrategyTranslatedFieldsSchema
  }
},
{
    timestamps: true 
});  

const Strategy = mongoose.model('strategy', StrategySchema);

module.exports = Strategy;
```

Also interesting is it good practice to save multilingual data, like that example?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
 // create object you want to pass StrategySchema 
 const strategySchemaObject = {
     slug: { 
         type: String, 
         slug: "en.title", 
         slugPaddingSize: 2,  
         unique: true 
     },
     status:{
         type: Boolean,
         default: true
    }
  }

  // add each field to your schema object
  Object.keys(Language.schema.obj).forEach((lang) => {
      strategySchemaObject[lang] = StrategyTranslatedFieldsSchema
   })

  // create your schema
  const StrategySchema = mongoose.Schema(strategySchemaObject, {
      timestamps: true
  })
```

Comment: it's throw error on Language forEach, that Language.forEach is not a function.
I try first get all languages but still not working
const getLanguages = async function(){
  return await Language.find();
}
const languagies =  getLanguages(); 

languagies.forEach((lang) => {
  strategySchemaObject[lang] = StrategyTranslatedFieldsSchema
})

Comment: @Ali your language is a model I guess right? No what your are trying to do is trying to search db. Maybe try creating an array with all the language that you support.

Comment: yes, I save them also on Db

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I need. But it is throw error on foreach. I need take languages from DB and loop them keys

Comment: Throw same error (Language.schema.obj.forEach)

Comment: Debug and check what you get by logging this `Language.schema.obj` if its a object do `Object.keys(Language.schema.obj).forEach`

Comment: Yeah, it was object. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ali please accept answer if it works.

Comment: Done it, hope correctly